# NSDate Formatting

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date string as follows: "Fri, 17 Jun 2011 19:20:51 PDT" which I need to parse into an `NSDate` format.

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"];
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentPubDate ];
 [dateFormatter release];
```

The code doesn't appear to be working and I am not sure why. I have looked into the issue but searching through forums etc and can't seem to find an answer. I do believe it is an issue with the `dateFormatter`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You incorrectly specified your `setDateFormat` string. This is how you should have specified it:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

`YYYY` is only used in the "Week date" format used for some industrial and commercial applications. It looks like this: `YYYY-Www-D` where 2011-W1-3 would equate to the third day of the first week of 2011.

The Apple docs note that it is a common mistake to use `YYYY` instead of `yyyy`: [Fixed Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing MM with MMM -- I dont have XCode handy to verify but typically "M" or "MM" will refer to numeric month. In your case since you have "Jun" you should try MMM.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

`NSDateFormatter` has the properties: `dateStyle` & `timeStyle`

You can set these to `NSDateFormatterNoStyle`, `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`, `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`, `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`, `NSDateFormatterFullStyle`

Once these are set you can use `stringFromDate:` to get a nicely formatted string.

Check out the documentation page for each style does to the time and date.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle

Cheers!